# View permissions on specific Oracle object

Tags: oracle

I want to be able to see what permissions have been granted on a specific object in my Oracle geodatabase. What would my syntax look like in SQL Plus?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check object privileges on tables through the view dba_tab_privs.

Here's a query:

```
SELECT grantee, privilege FROM dba_tab_privs WHERE table_name='XXXXX';
```

You can also learn more about privileges and stuff from this really cool website:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/forensics/t_forensics_object_privileges.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot. Burleson is the man. I knew it was something along those lines but couldn't get it. Thanks Eric!

Comment: No problem, man! Have a good night.